# Wheelchart contour seems not to work in the wheelchart package version 2.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3

I use the wheelchart package https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart?lang=en. I'm trying to get the "contour" key to work. When I create the example without "contour" everything works, as soon as I add "contour", I get the error:

> Undefined control sequence. }
> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. }

Here's the code copied from the manual:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn
\tl_gset:Nn {Ne}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF {enF}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn {Ne}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nVTF} 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn {en} 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn {Ne} 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn {ce} 
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe 
\cs_set:Npx \cs_set_eq:NN 
\cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \colorlet{good}{green!75!black}
    \colorlet{bad}{red}
    \colorlet{neutral}{black!60}
    \colorlet{none}{white}
    \wheelchart[
    anchor xsep=15,
    contour=gray,
    data={“\WCvarC”: \WCvarA{} (\WCperc)},
    middle={Ratings given by\\\pgfmathprintnumber{\WCtotalnum}~participants},
    radius={1.8}{2.2},
    start half=270,
    wheel lines={black!15,thick}
    ]{%
        10/neutral/ok,
        9/good!60!white/good,
        3/good/{very good},
        20/none/none,
        0/bad/{very bad},
        8/bad!60!white/bad%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code from your question works without error for me. Can you show your .log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then the version of expl3 is not up to date enough. It is probably sufficient to add the two lines marked in the code below with `%added` at the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gset:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { enF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nVTF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { en }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn { ce }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_build_gput_left:Nn { Ne }%added
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_build_gput_right:Nn { Ne }%added
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe \cs_set:Npx
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\colorlet{good}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{bad}{red}
\colorlet{neutral}{black!60}
\colorlet{none}{white}
\wheelchart[
    anchor xsep=15,
    contour=gray,
    data=``\WCvarC'': \WCvarA{} (\WCperc),
    middle=Ratings given by\\\WCtotalnum{} participants,
    radius={1.8}{2.2},
    start half=270,
    wheel lines={black!15,thick}
]{%
    10/neutral/ok,
    9/good!60!white/good,
    3/good/very good,
    20/none/none,
    0/bad/very bad,
    8/bad!60!white/bad%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I have the pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 version (TeX Live 2023). How can I get a more up-to-date expl3 version? (thanks for the fast reply and the very useful package)

Comment: @NicolasAndre Thank you! See for example this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution