# Arc data in wheelchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

**Problem**

I am trying to build a wheel chart diagram with the text curved on the wheel (similar to the spiral example on page 34 of https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/wheelchart/wheelchart.pdf, but as a circle).

The main problem seems to be that this features requires a newer version of the package which I can not get to run on my machine.

**Current Wheel Chart**

Without the curved text, the result looks like this:

[image]

**Steps Taken**

It seems that the texlive-pictures (2022.20230122-3) distributed by my package manager only includes wheelchart version 1.0. This does not include the "arc" keyword, which was added in wheelchart version 2.0 in December 2023.

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/wheelchart/arc data'

So I downloaded the wheelchart.sty file from CTAN and put it in the same directory.

Then I got the following message, which according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708483/315903 could be a hint to an outdated version of expl3:

> Undefined control sequence. \pgfkeys@code #1\pgfeov ->\tl_gset:Ne \g__wheelchart_name_tl {#1} l.2178   }", which according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708483/315903 could be a hint to an outdated version of expl3.

Hence, I tried adding the code in the MWE above "\usepackage{wheelchart}". This seemed to solve the issue above and similar subsequent ones, but now I am stuck at:

> Missing number, treated as zero.  \relax l.136 ...csname newcount\endcsname \scratchcounter

**Question**

Does anybody have any idea how to fix that problem?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
%\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gset:Nn { Ne }
%\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF {enF}
%\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn {en}
%\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    data =,
    wheel data = \WCvarC,
    %arc data = \WCvarC,     % This is what I want to use instead of the above.
    ]{
        1/red/Text,
        2/green/More Text,
        3/yellow/Even More Text
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi dn1h, what are you running it through?n I have just tried on Miktex and it renders fine, I even added the arc data pos like on Pg 34.

Comment: I am using texlive-pictures (2022.20230122-3), which only includes wheelchart version 1.0. Also added above - thank you for asking!

Comment: Hi @dn1h, not sure if you solved it but I just downloaded texlive for Mac and then updated all the packages in texlive utility and now it works for me there as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure that with an up to date package version the problem will vanish. The problem is that I am bound to version 1.0 delivered by the texlive version of my distribution.

Comment: Sorry can't help you then, but I advise you to reword your question to that of, asking how to update a package on your specific distributor. With tags including that info, as it might get a different audience than people with Tikg-pgf knowledge. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: As described, I already updated the package by manually adding version 2 to the local directory of the *.tex file. Now I am trying to fix the problems there. But it might be easier to set up a separate vm with another os with an up to date version of all texlive.

Comment: "Solved" by using a separate vm with the current texlive version and wheelchart version 2.0. The original question remains open, however.