How to produce pgf-pie from an etoolbox dolistloop?
I have a an etoolbox list with some sort of labels, one counter per label. I'd like to produce a pgf-pie chart from these labels and their counter values. But two problems:

PGF Math complains about "unknown function"
No idea how to get rid of the trailing comma produced by the loop (convert dolistloop result into string and remove last character, maybe??)

Example below. Thanks!
/Holger
\documentclass[tikz]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}


\begin{document}

% just to set up some example values: 
\listadd{\wplist}{A}
\listadd{\wplist}{B}
\listadd{\wplist}{C}
\listadd{\wplist}{D}

\newcounter{WP-A} \setcounter{WP-A}{10}
\newcounter{WP-B} \setcounter{WP-B}{20}
\newcounter{WP-C} \setcounter{WP-C}{30}
\newcounter{WP-D} \setcounter{WP-D}{40}


% this works as expected, produces
% A: 10 B: 20 C: 30 D: 40
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{#1: \arabic{WP-#1} }
\dolistloop{\wplist}

\renewcommand{\do}[1]{\arabic{WP-#1}/#1, }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % This works: 
  % \pie{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}

  % This fails:
  % ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `A' (in '10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D, ').
  \pie{\dolistloop{\wplist}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


In the answer below, the function \exp_args:Ne exhaustively expands the argument of the command \pie so that \pie reads 10/A,20/B,30/C,40/D.
The trailing comma is removed with \clist_use:nn. Also here, \exp_args:Ne is used to exhaustively expand the first argument of \clist_use:nn.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
%note the usage of % to remove spaces: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453
\listadd{\wplist}{A}%
\listadd{\wplist}{B}%
\listadd{\wplist}{C}%
\listadd{\wplist}{D}%
\newcounter{WP-A}\setcounter{WP-A}{10}%
\newcounter{WP-B}\setcounter{WP-B}{20}%
\newcounter{WP-C}\setcounter{WP-C}{30}%
\newcounter{WP-D}\setcounter{WP-D}{40}%
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{\arabic{WP-#1}/#1,}%
%\ExplSyntaxOn
%this gives 10/A,20/B,30/C,40/D
%\exp_args:Ne \clist_use:nn { \dolistloop { \wplist } } { , }
%\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Ne \pie { \exp_args:Ne \clist_use:nn { \dolistloop { \wplist } } { , } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Edit: it is also possible to use \clist_put_right:Nn in the command \do. Then the code for the commmand \pie can be simplified to \exp_args:No \pie { \l__Holger_piedata_clist }. See the code below. This still requires the command \exp_args:No. Further below is an alternative solution with the package wheelchart which I wrote that does not require a command such as \exp_args:No.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
%note the usage of % to remove spaces: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453
\listadd{\wplist}{A}%
\listadd{\wplist}{B}%
\listadd{\wplist}{C}%
\listadd{\wplist}{D}%
\newcounter{WP-A}\setcounter{WP-A}{10}%
\newcounter{WP-B}\setcounter{WP-B}{20}%
\newcounter{WP-C}\setcounter{WP-C}{30}%
\newcounter{WP-D}\setcounter{WP-D}{40}%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__Holger_piedata_clist
\renewcommand { \do } [ 1 ]
  { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__Holger_piedata_clist { \arabic { WP-#1 } / #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\dolistloop{\wplist}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:No \pie { \l__Holger_piedata_clist }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Instead of using the package etoolbox, it is also possible to omit this package and to use expl3 as in the answer from egreg and as in the code below.
The command \pie expects an argument of the form <value>/<data>,.... It may be desirable to use 2 separate lists for the values and the data. This is possible by combining these 2 separate lists and putting them in the form <value>/<data>,... as expected by the command \pie. It might be more convenient to use those 2 separate lists for the values and the data directly. This is done in the answer below, which uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The keys data and value are defined with \clist_item:Nn of their respective clist. Here, \WCcount gives the current number of the slice.
The command \addto takes 2 arguments. The first one is value or data. The second argument consists of 1 element or a list of elements and will be appended to the respective list for the values or the data.
The command \addtovalueanddata appends elements to the list for the values and the data simultaneously.
The command \minimumofvalueanddata is the minimum of the number of elements in the list for the values and the list for the data. The minimum is taken for in case that one list contains more elements than the other. This command is used in the key total count.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__Holger_data_clist
\clist_new:N \l__Holger_value_clist
\pgfkeys
  {
    / wheelchart ,
    counterclockwise ,
    data = \clist_item:Nn \l__Holger_data_clist { \WCcount } ,
    pie ,
    slices~style = { \WClistcolors , draw = black , thick } ,
    start~angle = 0 ,
    value = \clist_item:Nn \l__Holger_value_clist { \WCcount } ,
    WClistcolors = { blue!60 , cyan!60 , yellow!60 , orange!60 , red!60 , blue!60!cyan!60 , cyan!60!yellow!60 , red!60!cyan!60 , red!60!blue!60 , orange!60!cyan!60 } ,
    wheel~data = \WCperc
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \addto { m m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      { \clist_put_right:cn { l__Holger_#1_clist } { {##1} } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \addtovalueanddata { m m }
  {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__Holger_value_clist {#1}
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__Holger_data_clist {#2}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \minimumofvalueanddata {}
  { \int_min:nn { \clist_count:N \l__Holger_value_clist } { \clist_count:N \l__Holger_data_clist } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
%note the usage of % to remove spaces: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453
\addto{value}{10,20}%
\addto{value}{30}%
\addto{data}{A}%
\addto{data}{{B,b},C}%
\addtovalueanddata{40}{D}%
\addto{data}{more text}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  total count=\minimumofvalueanddata
]{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: if the usage of the package etoolbox and the counters need to be preserved then this can be achieved as in the code below. Similarly as in a solution above, \clist_put_right:Nn is used in the command \do. Then \wheelchart { \l__Holger_data_clist } can be used directly whereas above the command \exp_args:No was needed in \exp_args:No \pie { \l__Holger_piedata_clist }. The values are obtained from the counters using the key value=\value{WP-\WCvarA}.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCvarA,
  pie,
  slices style={\WClistcolors,draw=black,thick},
  start angle=0,
  value=\value{WP-\WCvarA},
  WClistcolors={blue!60,cyan!60,yellow!60,orange!60,red!60,blue!60!cyan!60,cyan!60!yellow!60,red!60!cyan!60,red!60!blue!60,orange!60!cyan!60},
  wheel data=\WCperc
}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__Holger_data_clist
\renewcommand { \do } [ 1 ]
  { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__Holger_data_clist {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%note the usage of % to remove spaces: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453
\listadd{\wplist}{A}%
\listadd{\wplist}{B}%
\listadd{\wplist}{C}%
\listadd{\wplist}{D}%
\newcounter{WP-A}\setcounter{WP-A}{10}%
\newcounter{WP-B}\setcounter{WP-B}{20}%
\newcounter{WP-C}\setcounter{WP-C}{30}%
\newcounter{WP-D}\setcounter{WP-D}{40}%
\dolistloop{\wplist}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\wheelchart { \l__Holger_data_clist }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks, very helpful! Wheelchart looks great, but I cannot run your example? The current version 4.0 gives
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeys@code #1\pgfeov ->\tl_gset:Ne
                                      \g__wheelchart_name_tl {#1}

and my 2022 version is probably too old? Like have to reinstall TexLive from scratch.

@HolgerKarl In that case, the version of expl3 is not up to date enough, as you already indicated. It is not necessary to reinstall TeXLive. It is probably sufficient to put the following before \usepackage{wheelchart} (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708483/290058): (Continues in next comment)

\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gset:Nn { Ne } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { enF } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { NVTF } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { en } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Ne } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn { ce } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_build_put_right:Nn { Ne } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Npn { Npe , cpe } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { eeTF } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nne , Nno , Nee } \ExplSyntaxOff

\pie wants to be fed with a comma separated list of items having the form <number>/<label>. However \dolistloop produces a set of instructions for printing the list. Not the list itself.
I see no reason for defining counters.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newpie}{m}
 {% #1 = pie name
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_holger_pie_#1_clist }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtopie}{mmm}
 {% #1 = pie name, #2 = label, #3 = amount
  \clist_put_right:cn { l_holger_pie_#1_clist } { #3/{#2} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makepie}{O{}m}
 {% #1 = options, #2 = pie name
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \holger_pie:nv {#1} { l_holger_pie_#2_clist }
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \holger_pie:nn { \pie[#1]{#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \holger_pie:nn {nv}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newpie{test}
\addtopie{test}{A}{10}
\addtopie{test}{B}{20}
\addtopie{test}{C}{30}
\addtopie{test}{D}{40}
\newpie{animals}
\addtopie{animals}{gnu}{43}
\addtopie{animals}{gnat}{2}
\addtopie{animals}{bear}{54}
\addtopie{animals}{ant}{1}

\makepie{test}

\makepie[pos={8,0}, explode=0.1]{animals}

\end{document}



Very helpful, thanks. the counters come from other parts of the document (legacy, and I don't have the time to rewrite that, although of course that would be the clean thing to do). I'll see how to put that solution and the one below together.
